# A new Thing observed in "Scanf"

Tags: programming-languages, c

Generally the 'scanf' syntax typically appears as scanf ( , arg1, arg2, arg3, ... ) ;

But even though Format characters are %d,%s,%c...,but i noticed a new format character like

"%[^\n]" in the program code as scanf("%[^\n]",ptr) ,what does "%[^\n]" specify there,is it a new format character

If this question doesnt fit here i am sorry,
thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

It isn't new; it's part of standard C.  You'll find what it does discussed in the [`scanf` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and [this part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html).

Comment: Or in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (3.7 MB PDF), section 7.19.6.2.